# Treat a lot of (same) inputs in 1 form?

Tags: php, sql, forms, input, pdo

I'm new into PHP-PDO, I'm trying to learn how to use classes and I think I'll have to use it.

So I'm creating an admin panel to post "news" and I need a lot of inputs:

[image]

These data will be used to fill an array on the homepage of the website to present the "daily bets" I recommend.

But I don't know the best way to treat these informations ? I thought of renaming the `<input>` into name="1", name="2" etc. but that would be a disaster to register everything in MySQL.

Someone may have an idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same `name` to every field as an array, for example, `sports[]`. This, when you submit the form, will create an array with all the "sports" in it.

```
<input type="text" name="sports[]">
<input type="text" name="game[]">
<input type="text" name="prediction[]">
```

If, for instance, you send football, soccer, baseball, basketball; then, your PHP will be the following:

```
$sports = $_POST['sports'];
// now:
// $sports[0] = 'football'
// $sports[1] = 'soccer'
// $sports[2] = 'baseball'
// $sports[3] = 'basketball'
```

So all you have to do is to loop through `$sports` (and all the inputs you have) to get their corresponding value. It is sorted in order of appearance.

```
foreach($sports as $k => $v){
    $sport = $v; // $k will have the 0, 1, 2, 3 (indexes) if you need them.
                 // $v will have 'football', 'soccer' and so on.
                 // in other words, this loop will run 4 times in my example.
    // you should do SQL stuff here, each item independently (if you need to)
}
```